# Trying to compile linux build of project, cannot find library

Tags: linux, build, compilation, linux-mint

I am trying to build a project written in c++ on Linux Mint 16, using...
`make -f ./Makefile`
and I keep getting this error

```
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ludev
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [BINARY] Error 1
```

I was getting a lot more of the `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -foo`, but I checked in my Makefile and, using the synaptic package manager, installed all the other necessary libraries, eliminating all but this error. I cant seem to find it anywhere, although perhaps I am not looking in the right places.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem, right after updating to Linux Mint 17.1. I was trying to build an application with Qt 5 serial port module. Solved by installing: `libudev-dev` .

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo apt-get install udev
```

I don't know how to do that in synaptic, but it should be easier, right?